# How to eliminate the requirement to lock files which are executed?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2008, shared-folders, lock

I have an application which is placed onto it's dedicated server. It has plugin-able structure. It was imagined as soft which has some features from web apps like ability to replace it's modules "on-the fly", while other users have this app launched in their userspace.

To implement this feature, I made single launcher with number of plugins and placed it into shared folder. Let it be `C:\App`. There is EXE called `MultiPlug2.exe` and all the plugins are placed in `C:\App\Plugins` and have `.bpl` extension (yep, damn good old Delphi XE2 is used as IDE, and I hate the day I decided to use it). The launcher is `Start.cmd` which checks if current user has `%USERPROFILE%\App` folder and creates it if he hasn't. Then it creates symbolic links for each EXE and BPL (i.e. `mklink linkname target`, and I allowed creating symbolic links in server policies) in those folders. Then it starts `%USERPROFILE%\App\MultiPlug2.exe`.

After launch, for a while, I can manipulate files in target folders, especially delete and replace them, but soon they become locked as if I was launching `MultiPlug2` directly from the folder in which it lies. How can I stop theirs locking?

Answer (score 0):

Are these files in `%USERPROFILE%\App` just a symbolic link to the ones under `C:\App`? If so then users are actually running it right from the original folder. A symbolic link isn't a copy of the original file, it is the original file.

Comment: I know that should be correct, but for a while they are not locked. If I run program straight from the folder, it locks immediately.